# Create "Flattened" Data Label Columns from Multiple Lists

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I want to create a "flattened" data structure in Excel for several data labels with listed attributes. For example:

I have the following lists of data:

```
Date     Department  Forecast Period
Jan-16   Marketing    2015 Nov
Feb-16   Accounting   2015 Dec
Mar-16   HR 
Apr-16
```

I want to transform the above into the following data structure:

```
Date    Department  Forecast Period
Jan-16  Marketing   2015 Nov
Jan-16  Marketing   2015 Dec
Jan-16  Accounting  2015 Nov
Jan-16  Accounting  2015 Dec
Jan-16  HR          2015 Nov
Jan-16  HR          2015 Dec
Feb-16  Marketing   2015 Nov
Feb-16  Marketing   2015 Dec
Feb-16  Accounting  2015 Nov
Feb-16  Accounting  2015 Dec
Feb-16  HR          2015 Nov
Feb-16  HR          2015 Dec
Mar-16  Marketing   2015 Nov
Mar-16  Marketing   2015 Dec
Mar-16  Accounting  2015 Nov
Mar-16  Accounting  2015 Dec
Mar-16  HR          2015 Nov
Mar-16  HR          2015 Dec
Apr-16  Marketing   2015 Nov
Apr-16  Marketing   2015 Dec
Apr-16  Accounting  2015 Nov
Apr-16  Accounting  2015 Dec
Apr-16  HR          2015 Nov
Apr-16  HR          2015 Dec
```

Ideally, I would also be able to add/remove items from the first three lists and the transformed data would adjust accordingly. I'm not sure if VBA or formulas would be the best way to tackle this, but hopefully you will be able to give me some guidance.

Comment: Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three formulas:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)),INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/((COUNTA(B:B)-1)*(COUNTA(C:C)-1)))+2),"")

=IF(E2<>"",INDEX(B:B,MOD(INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/(COUNTA(C:C)-1)),COUNTA(B:B)-1)+2),"")

=IF(E2<>"",INDEX(C:C,MOD((ROW(1:1)-1),COUNTA(C:C)-1)+2),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for this solution Scott. This looks to work great. Apologies if I've broken a rule on this section of the site--I was under the impression that this would constitute a question. As one follow up, would it be easy to extrapolate the formula I'd need to add a fourth column from the formula's that you provided? It looks like it would be fairly straightforward, but I'm by no means an expert in this type of analysis.

Comment: @Ben normally it is expected to show what you have tried and where it is failing, especially when requesting vba code.  As you also indicated you wanted a formula **AND** I found this an intriguing puzzle, I answered.  I also voted to close it as too broad.  Just remember that next time when you ask come with what you have tried and were it went wrong.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me site it is to help overcome problematic code.

Comment: @Ben as far as adding a column, it is not too difficult, try on your own.  If you are not able to do it, then come back and ask a new question.  Post what you have tried to modify the above formulas and link to this question.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for your help.